# Questions about static methods and the call stack

Tags: java, jvm

Say if we have this code

```
public static void count(){int i++}

public static void main(String args[])
{
 System.out.println("Not calling the count method");
}
```

When will the JVM know how much memory and when to push the count() method onto the stack?

I assume it's allocated on the stack. IF that is true, then how does the JVM know to push an objects methods onto the stack, or are they called from the heap.?

Say if we have an object and it has a method (non static). In main, we then create an object and do not call any methods on it. Does the method that the object have still get allocated into memory some how?

Are static methods in java pushed onto the stack at compile time? How about non static methods from an object?

Comment: There is no stack at compile time. Nor are addresses put on the stack until they are used in the program. The fact that this is a static method actually has no bearing on that.

Comment: I thought that when you call a method, it gets pushed onto the stack (parameters, local variables, return address...)

Comment: The return address / parameters / local variables is not the same thing as "the method".

Comment: so the "method" is stored in the "code" segment, or is it not stored anywhere/

Comment: Obviously the bytecode is *somewhere* in memory, otherwise the JVM would not be able to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all word 'stack' can be used in two cases: memory management and order of calling methods/functions

You can see call stack for example, when exception is thrown. I would leave difference between memory stack and heap just for a while -it's just memory. Method is a set of instructions with some additional locally defined variables (primitive types, others are references like the rest) and this, defines the size of stack "frame", memory it needs  depends mostly on this and some JVM stuff. When you remove "static" nothing will change in this area. The method exists somewhere in memory and when it is called the stack frame is created with local variables, references to arguments, return value, etc. Method "body" is most probably (not 100% sure) copied anywhere, because this is just a set of instructions to be performed on data in created frame.

I think this article can help you to understand method calling http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm2.html. Static methods and normal ones are equal in case of calling and puting them on top of stack. So to answer one of your question: method goes to the stack when it is called, no matter static, final or regular.

And remember not to mix memory stack and call stack terms.

Answer (score 3):

You have misconceptions about how the JVM executes Java code, or you are using terminology the wrong way.

Methods are not pushed onto the stack. Methods are not "called from the heap" (it's not even clear what you mean by that). Nothing is pushed onto the stack at compile time; the call stack only exists at runtime.

The JVM has a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). That means that anytime when you call a method, the JVM puts the return address and method arguments on the stack. When the method returns, the return address is popped, so that the JVM knows where to continue executing code. There is no difference between instance methods and `static` methods with regards to this.

There is only one copy of the bytecode of a method. Since the bytecode of a method does not change at runtime, it would not make any sense to copy the code of the method for every instance of a class (no matter if the method is `static` or not).

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about the stack and the heap, we are talking about *data* storage.

*Code* is a completely different matter and typically lives outside those storage areas. Specifically, it is very likely that on your architecture there is a fixed runtime memory cost for declaring a method in a class. This cost does not depend on how many instances of the class you then create.

Put another way, one copy of the method's code can service any number of instances of the class.